# Regarding this difference equation

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, recurrence-relations

Consider the inhomogeneous difference equation

$$u_n=u_{n-1}+u_{n-2}+\dots+u_1+1$$

where we have the initial condition $u_1=1$

Clearly $u_n=2^{n-1}$ is a solution.

However, plugging a solution of the form $u_n=kx^n$ into the homogeneous difference equation gives the auxiliary equation/polynomial:

$x^n=x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\dots+x$

It's clear $2$ is not a root of this. Is there an explanation for why this is? I'm thinking $u_n=2^{n-1}$ just happens to be a particular solution and the homogeneous solution just happens to be 0 due to the initial condition. However, I think particular solutions of inhomogeneous difference equations where the forcing term is a constant generally isn't some constant raised to the power $n$ (it's usually a polynomial in $n$) so I'm not sure if this explanation is correct?

Comment: It isn't the kind of difference equation you are thinking about.  Those have a fixed number of terms.  Here the number of terms is different for every $n$.  The theory you are thinking of doesn't apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re trying to apply a method for solving recurrences of fixed order to one that is not of fixed order. You can, however, rewrite it: $u_{n-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}u_k$, so

$$u_n=u_{n-1}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}u_k=2u_{n-1}\,,$$

and you now have a *very* simple homogeneous first-order recurrence.

Comment: Thank you! I did suspect it might have something to do with the recurrences needing to have fixed order but wasn't sure. That makes it much clearer.

Comment: @123456: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You dropped the 1. And lets also set the solution more precisely $u_n = kx^{n-1}$ since your power of two solution is also $n-1$. Because then the $u_1$ term would add another 1 by being power of 0.

$x^n = x^{n-1} + ... + x + x^0 + 1$

We can confirm for $n = 2$, that $x^2 = x + 2$ admits a solution $x = 2 = 2^{2-1}$.

I haven't really confirmed this should work all the way up, but it's promising.